# I need to scrape that number xpath + aspx

Tags: xpath

I'm trying to get the total number of the page (or the page value) of this URL:

http://scorelibrary.fabermusic.com/String-Quartet-No-2-300-Weihnachtslieder-23032.aspx

```
1/58
```

I think that I can't because the values are inside in the ASPX frame.

I'll try a lot of thing. This is the line:

```
<label id="page_count">1/58</label>
```

using the following XPath

```
//label[@id='page_count']/text()
```

How can I use XPath inside the ASPX frame to get the page value?

Comment: Maybe add the relevant tags (!!!) - from this code I can't tell whether it is `html` or `xml`. I suggest visiting [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in order to get a better insight on how to ask a solid question. Additionally, some code, errors, and a slightly better explanation is necessary in order for others to offer you help (they 1st need to understand what the actual issue is). Hang in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, you cannot get that value directly because the element is in an `<iframe>`, and therefore lives in a different context. You need to activate or switch to the URL context of the `iframe`. There are JavaScript [approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52453352/8291949) like [postMessage](https://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/iframes/postmessage/), but I think the easiest way is loading the [URL](https://www.epartnershub.com/engravingservices/view.aspx?q=48F7F1B48CCA6FB595AAC26CC79871E702ADA655D25FFABDC9B01FD1D8E55E6D) of the iframe directly and access the DOM from there.

Comment: Thanks for your message. In the chrome developer tools that is working: xpath('//*[@id="page_count"]/text()')  but not in python, the script returns me [].

Comment: I discover that I cant read the value because when I get the web (python request) and keep in a variable, the value is not set yet. The script keep the raw of the website but the website is not generates the value of the total pages !!! Now, I have to discover the way to "wait" for that number and keep it. Thanks

Comment: @Maxwell If you use Selenium you can specify the wait time, e.g. `WebDriverWait(browser, 3).until(...` See: https://blog.codeship.com/get-selenium-to-wait-for-page-load/

Comment: Thanks, @wp78de. I solved reading the value from JSON. Thanks for ur answer. I never used Selenium. I will take a look over it. Thanks again.